# ORA-00972 error from dbms_cube.import_xml() call

Tags: oracle, olap-cube

I create a cube by hand in AWM, and export it as a template. But when I try to import it with
`dbms_cube.import_xml('/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/XML_DIR','test.xml')`, it throws an ORA-00972 error.

```
ORA-00972: 
ORA-06512:  "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 744
ORA-06512:  "SYS.DBMS_CUBE", line 334
ORA-06512:  "SYS.DBMS_CUBE", line 478
ORA-06512:  "SYS.DBMS_CUBE", line 491
ORA-06512:  line 1
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
```

I could use AWM to import the template successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The [`IMPORT_XML` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_cube.htm#CHDEDJIH) expects the name of a database directory object, not an operating system directory path.

The value you're passing is taken as the name of a directory object, as would be shown in `DBA_DIRECTORIES` etc. The length is therefore limited to 30 characters by the object naming rules. You are passing in a 34-character path, which is too long to be an object name (identifier), and it's that which generates the ORA-00972; but even if it was shorter it would not be a valid database directory object name.

If you have a [directory object](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/glossary.htm#CNCPT44466) called `XML_DIR` defined against path `/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/XML_DIR`, you can call this as:

```
dbms_cube.import_xml('XML_DIR','test.xml')
```

You can read more about creating drectory objects [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5007.htm).

Comment: Excellent, now it works although other error raised. Thanks for your great help.